# Changing Tabulator cell color through cell formatter is removing the value displayed

Tags: javascript, css, dom, tabulator

I'm trying to change the color of a tabulator cell based on the input of the cell. My first step was to just simply try and change the color of the cell. Run the following code, I see the following

```js
function testFormatter(cell, formatterParams) {

    cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#A6A6DF";

}
```

[Here is what my table looks like after using the cell formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0labR.jpg)

I apologize if I get back to you late. This is my first StackOverflow post and I don't know how long replies usually take to come in.

Comment: Is your text the same color as the background color? Check if the cell content exists with DevTools.

Comment: @sean-7777 thank you my dude for responding! That was not the issue, the documentation didn't mention it but custom cell formatters MUST return a value, so all i had to do was get the cell data and return it (see my solution below), thanks again for trying to help!

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the solution. The documentation doesn't say it, but custom formatters HAVE to return a value in some way, shape or form.

So the code to rectify the issue would simply be the following:

```js
function testFormatter(cell, formatterParams) {
    var bvid = cell.getValue();
    cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#A6A6DF";
    return bvid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For all cells:

```
    formatter: function (cell) {
        let val = cell.getValue();
        let el = cell.getElement();

        el.style.backgroundColor = "#A6A6DF";

        return val;
    }
```

For a cell that math condition:

```
    formatter: function (cell) {
        let val = cell.getValue();
        let el = cell.getElement();

        if (val == "some text") {
            el.style.backgroundColor = "#A6A6DF";
        }

        return val;
    }
```

Comment: i left the company that had me doing this 6 months ago, but i appreciate the knowledge sharing !